# Why is it not ok to catch Exception instead of the more specific URLError?

Tags: python

```
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except Exception, e:
    logger.exception(e)
```

Is there any convincing argument against catching `Exception` instead of `urllib2.URLError` in this code snippet ?

Comment: Other than the usual argument for *never* catching `Exception`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are could be unexpected reasons that an exception could be raised here that you don't or can't know about. You write your program as though the only exception here could be  `urllib2.URLError`, and then one day something in the internals of `urllib2` generates an exception that isn't one of those. It could be a bug, it could be something that only happens on full moons, it could be some future brand of exception that you never designed for.

Do you **really** want to continue unimpeded if those happen?

More generally, the type of exception you catch is an integral part of your program's logic. If you're not specific enough, you have a logical error, end of story — same as if you leave out a clause from an `if` statement.

Comment: ctrl-c causes a `KeyboardInterrupt`. another notable exception is `SystemExit` which is raised by `sys.exit()`

Comment: All the exceptions you mentioned are not subclasses of `Exception` and will not get caught!

Comment: @mg - thanks, I was channelling my Java days. @Jochen - oops, I didn't think of that. I never try to catch them, you see :P I think my general point still stands.

Comment: @mg, @Jochen - fixed it up now.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> try: response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
... except Exception, e: print e
... 
name 'req' is not defined
>>>
```

Not too much meaningful, neither your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, or not, depends on context. If there is only one type exception can happen, or you do not care about separate processing different types of problem, then catching simply Exception is completely fine. It has also no performance impact. However if your code supposes to be used and modified by other people, you can improve readability providing specific exception.